# Using PowerShell to start batch file for secure wipe USB drive

Tags: powershell, batch-file, start-process

I'm using PowerShell to start a bat file that wipes a USB drive that connected. 
If I use the script without `Start-Process` it works fine, but I'm wanting to connect multiple drives and have it wipe them simultaneously.

The script:

```bsh
Register-WmiEvent -Class Win32_VolumeChangeEvent -SourceIdentifier VolumeChange
Write-Host (Get-Date -Format s) " Beginning script..."
do {
    $newEvent = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
    $eventType = $newEvent.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.EventType
    $eventTypeName = switch ($eventType) {
        1 {"Configuration changed"}
        2 {"Device arrival"}
        3 {"Device removal"}
        4 {"docking"}
    }
    Write-Host (Get-Date -Format s) " Event detected = " $eventTypeName
    if ($eventType -eq 2) {
        $driveLetter = $newEvent.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.DriveName
        $driveLabel = ([wmi]"Win32_LogicalDisk='$driveLetter'").VolumeName
        Write-Host (Get-Date -Format s) " Drive name = " $driveLetter
        Write-Host (Get-Date -Format s) " Drive label = " $driveLabel
        # Execute process if drive matches specified condition(s)
        if ($driveLabel -eq 'BBIFREE_01' -or $drivelabel -eq 'HD10') {
            Write-Host (Get-Date -Format s) " Starting task in 3 seconds..."
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
            Start-Process -FilePath D:\wipe.bat $driveLetter, $driveLabel
            Copy-Item -Path D:\Utilities1 -Destination $driveLetter -Recurse

            $driveEject = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
            $driveEject.Namespace(17).ParseName($driveLetter).InvokeVerb("Eject")
        }
    }
    Remove-Event -SourceIdentifier VolumeChange
} while (1 -eq 1) #Loop until next event
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier VolumeChange
```

The bat file contents:

```batch
set arg1=%1
set arg2=%2

format %args1% /FS:NTFS /p:1 /V:%args2%  /x /y
```

**EDIT**

To clarify: the script is to run continously on a specific PC where it should start the bat file (as in wipe the disk securely) every time it detects a disk being connected. 
If I use:

```
D:\wipe.bat -ArgumentList `"$driveLetter",`"$driveLabel"
```

then it starts the wiping on 1 disk, and on 1 disk only.

I need it to detect multiple disks, that's why I used `Start-Process`, seeing as I thought it would run on the background and keep watching for new events.

**EDIT2**

I changed the code to avoid using `-ArgumentList`, see above.

If I put the `echo` command in my batch file as requested:

```batch
set arg1=E:
set arg2=BBIFREE_01
ECHO ECHO IS ON
ECHO ECHO IS ON
```

So I see the commands in the bat file, but it doesn't execute and goes straight for the copy command.

Comment: If I'm no totally wrong your bat file can't handle more than two arguments so you either have to start the batfile over and over again (times = number of connected drives) or you have to adapt your bat file to be able to process more than two arguments. So it will only process the first two arguments given regardless of how many there are. I have to admit though that I do not know what "-ArgumentList" does...

Comment: well the bat file is supposed to start anew with every drive connected. as in: Drive E: connected, start bat file, Drive F: connected start bat file again with 2 other arguments

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? As in, what's the issue with this script?

Comment: So your problem is rather detecting all connected drives the moment the script gets executed...? What happens now executing the script?

Comment: Wouldn't this script run every time a drive is connected? Or does it not start a new instance?

Comment: atm it doesn't seem to be doing anything, i see a brief cmd line flash (the start-process i presume) but it doesn't wipe the actual disk. The script is supposed to run continously and start the bat file every time it detects a new disk

Comment: try to echo the two arguments in the bat file and report back if it is echoed ...

Comment: so my batch file actually does get the arguments, see the first post

Comment: it seems you have a problem with your while condition... Your first drive gets wiped then? What happens with the second?

Comment: nothing, it gets ignored for some reason

Comment: Any reason you're not running the command directly from PowerShell?

Comment: Format-Volume isn't secure enough for my liking. The cmd command will write 0's for however many times you specify on the drive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a slightly modified version of a Script I wrote a while back, I don't have time right now to confirm it works 100% but it should at least point you in the right direction, it just threads the actual wiping so it can handle other jobs in the background, then uses a global popup to warn when one is done to prevent having to block while the job is finishing.

Should be able to handle any number of devices at once, it uses PowerShell's `Format-Volume` command instead, but you could put a call to the BAT file inside the job instead.

```
$USBWhiteList = @( #Add wildcard items here, if a USB matches one it will be wiped.
    "USB0*"
    "*WIPE"
)

Enum EventNames{ Changed = 1 ; Inserted = 2 ; Removed = 3 ; Docking = 4 } #Names for events
Register-WmiEvent -Class win32_VolumeChangeEvent -SourceIdentifier volumeChange -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue #register the event
do{
    Write-Host "Monitoring for Disk events..." -Fore Yellow
    $Event = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange #wait for a disk event
    $EventType = [EventNames]$Event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.EventType #get the type of the event
    Write-Host "Drive $($EventType), Processing..." -Fore Yellow -NoNewline
    $Volume = Get-Volume -DriveLetter $Event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.DriveName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue #get the volume details
    $IsMatch = ($USBWhiteList|? {$Volume.FileSystemLabel -like $_}).Count -gt 0 #does it match our whitelist?
    if (($EventType -eq [EventNames]::Inserted) -and $IsMatch){ #if a disk was inserted which matches the whitelist...
        Write-Host "Volume $($Volume.DriveLetter): '$($Volume.FileSystemLabel)', Found, Wiping!" -Fore Green
        Start-Job -ScriptBlock { param ($Volume) #Perform the wipe inside a job
            $Disk = Get-Partition -DriveLetter $Volume.DriveLetter | Get-Disk
            Clear-Disk -Number $Disk.Number -RemoveData -Confirm:$false
            New-Partition -DiskNumber $Disk.Number -UseMaximumSize -IsActive -DriveLetter $Volume.DriveLetter
            Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -DriveLetter $Volume.DriveLetter -Confirm:$false
            Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Windows.Forms' #warn (globally) when it is finished, don't need to run wait/recieve job.
            [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Finished Wiping Disk $($Volume.DriveLetter)","Please Remove Disk")
        } -ArgumentList $Volume | Out-Null
    } else {
        Write-Host "Ignoring" -Fore Red
    }
    Remove-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
} while (1) #this should be modified to quit after x disks or something, the below commands won't get exec'd - could also use a Try/Finally and Ctrl+C the script.
Get-Job | Remove-Job -Force
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
```

Comment: I haven't actually confirmed this will work at all so please tell me if there are any issues, I'd put this as a comment honestly if they didn't have a char limit.

Comment: `Format-Volume` does a quick format by default. You need to add `-Full` to make it write every sector, but even then I'm not sure it'll actually overwrite existing data like `format /p:1` does. I'd just do `Start-Job {& D:\wipe.bat @args} -Args $driveLetter, $driveLabel`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers my work laptop is preventing me from partitioning disks (thanks symantec encryption) but I've added in what should be a working full-powershell script, i'll test later when i'm home, or he can swap it out with his bat solution etc.